# Query About some Error Ditection in code

Tags: vb.net

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim tempport As Object
        Dim tempip As Object
        Dim tempid As Object
        Dim i As Integer
        serverid = m1.GetINISetting("STARTUP", "SERVERID" & i, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/svrinfo.ini")
        serverport = m1.GetINISetting("STARTUP", "PORT" & i, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/svrinfo.ini")
        serverip = m1.GetINISetting("STARTUP", "IP" & i, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/svrinfo.ini")
        agentid = m1.GetINISetting("STARTUP", "AGENTID" & i, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/svrinfo.ini")
        lblserverid.Text = serverid
        lblagentid.Text = agentid
        lblzoneport.Text = serverport
        lsip = m1.GetINISetting("LOGINSERVER", "IP", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/svrinfo.ini")
        lsport = CShort(m1.GetINISetting("LOGINSERVER", "PORT", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/svrinfo.ini"))
        zonecount = CShort(m1.GetINISetting("ZONESERVER", "COUNT", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/svrinfo.ini"))
        Dim zonelist(zonecount, 3)
        For i = 0 To zonecount - 1
            tempid = m1.GetINISetting("ZONESERVER", "ID" & i, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/svrinfo.ini")
            tempip = m1.GetINISetting("ZONESERVER", "IP" & i, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/svrinfo.ini")
            tempport = m1.GetINISetting("ZONESERVER", "PORT" & i, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/svrinfo.ini")
            If Not tempid = 0 Then sock_zone.Load(tempid)
            sock_zone(tempid).Protocol = MSWinsockLib.ProtocolConstants.sckTCPProtocol
            sock_zone(tempid).RemoteHost = tempip
            sock_zone(tempid).RemotePort = tempport
            sock_zone(tempid).Connect()
            zonelist(i, 0) = tempid
            zonelist(i, 1) = tempip
            zonelist(i, 2) = tempport
            combozoneiostatus.Items.Add((tempip & ":" & tempport & ":" & tempid))
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        Next i
        combozoneiostatus.SelectedIndex = 0
        sock_LS.Protocol = MSWinsockLib.ProtocolConstants.sckTCPProtocol
        sock_LS.RemoteHost = lsip
        sock_LS.RemotePort = lsport
        sock_LS.Connect()
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        Call refreshzonestatus()
        ReDim clientpreparedinfo(1, 4)
        ReDim clientinfo(1, 5)
        sock_client(0).Protocol = MSWinsockLib.ProtocolConstants.sckTCPProtocol
        sock_client(0).LocalPort = serverport
        sock_client.Load(1)
    End Sub
```

clientpreparedinfo & clientinfo 'ReDim' cannot change the number of dimensions of an array.
when i am adding Dim it gives Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; type of Object assumed.

Answer (score 1):

`Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; type of Object assumed` means that you are missing `As SomeType`. So it would be `Dim clientpreparedinfo(1,4) As SomeType` and `Dim clientinfo(1, 5) As SomeType` (replace SomeType with String, Integer or other type).

Comment: You must use Dim before ReDim and you can't change number of dimensions with ReDim. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbbx2zbe(v=vs.90).aspx